# Internet explorer url issue with special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, url, special-characters

I'm trying to fix a bug on a website and I get an issue with IE (all versions). The bug is the following:

- I have a page to display a document according to a code.
- But when the code contains special charachters like "ü" internet explorer want to download it rather than display it.
- In this case it's an picture but it can be a pdf or something the browser can display itself.
- The url is working with all others browsers...
- [https://example.com/GetDocument?codeDocument=testüblabla](https://example.com/GetDocument?codeDocument=test%C3%BCblabla)

Thank you for your reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already get the same issue, you can try that:

```
url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url, Encoding.UTF8);
```